# Run the date command in Spring Shell (“Cannot run program … the system cannot find the file specified”)

Tags: shell, spring-shell

As per the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-shell/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#d4e155) which says

> OsCommands - the keyword for this command is the exclamation point, after the exclamation 
>    point you can pass in a Unix/windows command string to be executed

This means, we can execute OS commands in Spring Shell by prefixing the OS command with `!` (exclamation).

But I believe there is some issue or I am missing something. When I tried, I got the below error.

```
hw-shell>! date
command is: date
Unable to execute command date [Cannot run program "date" (in directory "."): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified]
```

Answer (score 0):

I thinks you may be forgot to set class path in your spring shell class,Set the class path using below line then try...

`new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath*:/META-INF/spring/spring-shell-plugin.xml");`

For More Reference: http://docs.spring.io/spring-shell/docs/current/reference/html/shell.html

Comment: Jorg, thanks for the reply. I ran the sample program which normally comes along with the distribution. The Spring ApplicationContext is already configured. OS commands does not get executed only when I launch Spring shell in windows. In linux, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually have the "date" command in the %PATH% environment in windows, according to the exception message its missing.

Answer (score 0):

"date" is a built-in command of the windows command shell. It seems that these built-in commands are not available within spring-shell and spring-shell looks after commands which exist real as file in the windows path.

Windows-Commands like calc (`! calc`) which are not built-in are available.